# react-admin calls executes previous api request along with the new api request

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-admin

I am using React admin for our panel with grapqhl ,I noticed that there are lot duplicate or unwanted api calls to the backend with react-admin default pagination ,not sure whats wrong with my implementation .Look for some help here .Whenever i click on a page number the backend is called twice once with the previous page selection and another request with the current page selection

My List component

```
 <List {...props} filters={TitleFilter} actions={false} bulkActionButtons={false} pagination={<Pagination />}>
      <Datagrid bulkActionButtons={false}>
        <NumberField source='order' label='Position' />
        <TextField source='title' label='Titel' />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
```

and the network requests when i clicked on page 2, it is just overloading the backend with too many requests

[image]
[image]

Looks like this is not related to pagiantion, happening if i navigate to a different resource too , guessing the issue might be with caching

Comment: you have selected `Preserve Log`, so It keeps all ws call, you can see first screenshoot shows `page 1`, secong img shows `page 2`. So there may not be duplicate ws calls. Check when webservices were called. At the same time or not?

Comment: Also, you shared very limited code, so problem cannot be identified with what you shared. Can you post minimally reproducible code?

Comment: I cleared the network tab before a page change

Comment: your component that calls ws is being rendered 2 times, we can only guess with the code you shared, so you should share more code.

Comment: Would be worth going to the request and checking the `initiator` and see if/where something you aren't expecting is happening.